# How to create control dynamically?

Tags: angular

I have switch that calls specific method to create a form group:

```
 switch (option.id) {
         case DocumentBaseType.DocumentBaseRegister:
             this.createDocumentsElectronCooperation();
             break;
          case DocumentBaseType.DocumentsElectronCooperation:
               this.createDocumentsElectronCooperation();
              break;
}



private createDocumentsElectronCooperation(): void {
    this.form.addControl('date', this.createControl(null, []));
    this.form.addControl('number', this.createControl(null, []));
    this.form.addControl('documentTypes', this.formBuilder.array([]));
}

private createDocumentAnotherForm(): void {
    this.form.addControl('name', this.createControl(null, [Validators.required]));
}
```

Problem is that each time I need to remove all form controls that was presented in previos events. For exmaple, when I choose `DocumentBaseType.DocumentBaseRegister` I should remove all controls for `DocumentBaseType.DocumentsElectronCooperation` and vice versa.

Also there is a common part of form that are presented in all form types:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            appid: new FormControl(this.data?.appid, Validators.required),
            rootDocumentType: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            filename: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            _ts: new FormControl(null),
        });
```

How to solve this properly in Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to essentially pick one of several groups of extra controls, you don't need to modify the form programmatically - and I recommend you avoid that as much as possible, it's usually a source of trouble. (E.g., when resetting a form, you need to make sure it has the right structure before pushing the value.

Instead, just use a form group for each of the specialized control sets:

```
this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
  // The common controls for either document.
  appId: […],
  rootDocumentType: […],
  filename: […],
  _ts: […],
  // A group for each of your document types
  electronCooperationDetails: this.formBuilder.group({
    date: […],
    number: […],
    documentTypes: this._formBuilder.array([]),
  }),
  baseRegisterDetails: this.formBuilder.groups({
    name: […]
  })
})
```

(I'm the FormBuilder shorthand and omitting the control initialization for clarity.)

To switch on the right one, do something like:

```
function enableIf(control, value) {
  if (value) { control.enable(); } else { control.disable(); }
}
// … 
toggleDocumentDetails(baseTypeId) {
  enableIf(this.form.controls['electronCooperationDetails'], 
           baseTypeId === DocumentBaseType.DocumentsElectronCooperation);
  enableIf(this.form.controls['electronCooperationDetails'], 
           baseTypeId === DocumentBaseType. DocumentBaseType.DocumentBaseRegister);
}
// …
toggleDocumentDetails(option.id);
```

A disabled form subgroup's value will be `undefined` or not set in the value of `this.form`; it also won't trigger validations, and for *most* intents and purposes it's as if the form group's controls weren't there. (Off the top of my head I'm not sure if setting its value programatically works, but I believe it does, which would be an advantage.)

I put a more complete demo with how to display different form subgroups dynamically [on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-63993092?file=src/app/app.component.html). It uses a simpler example form though.

Comment: Could you provide template how to use it?

Comment: @user13314476 What do you mean by "template"? I wrote a bunch of code above that should cover what you described in your question.\

Comment: I mean howto use `electronCooperationDetails` in template or just to use as before?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't include any use of the form data, so I don't know what you'd be doing with it to demonstrate.

To render the form, you'd use something like: `<div *ngIf='this.form.controls.electronDetails.enabled'>[the UI for date, number, documentTypes]</div>`

Comment: How are you displaying your template now? I'll see if I can make a simplified demo but it won't match your controls or necessarily how you're switching the subtype.

Comment: I switch by mat-select passing id as you posted. But I can not ge thow to show common part and dinamic in template

Comment: @user13314476 - I added a link to a stackbiltz with a more complete example. `mat-select` should do the same basic thing my ratio buttons do in this case - the principle is you listen to changes on the variant select control, then selectively **enable** and **disable** the subgroups.

Comment: Thank you, I will try

Comment: I can not push to ` documentTypes: this.formBuilder.array([]),`

Comment: @user13314476 - I think this might stray a bit from the original question - I didn't really get as far as dealing with the dynamic array in the thing. If you have a "working" StackBlitz example, I'll be in chat for a short while; otherwise prepare an actual question with that problem if the switching subtypes works except for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221820/discussion-between-millimoose-and-user13314476).

Answer (score 0):

another aproach is use the same function to create all the controls

```
createForm(id)
{
  const form=this.formBuilder.group({
            appid: new FormControl(this.data?.appid, Validators.required),
            rootDocumentType: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            filename: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            _ts: new FormControl(null),
        });
  switch (id)
  {
    case DocumentBaseType.DocumentBaseRegister:
      form.addControl('date', this.createControl(null, []));
      form.addControl('number', this.createControl(null, []));
      form.addControl('documentTypes', this.formBuilder.array([]));
      break;
    case DocumentBaseType.DocumentsElectronCooperation:
      form.addControl('name', this.createControl(null, [Validators.required]));
      break;
  }
  return form;
  
}
```

then you make

```
this.form=this.createForm(opt.id)
```

Comment: Yes, but how to save statement of common part ?

Comment: you has an unique form, so in form.value you has all yours fields

Comment: Yes, but in your case every time form is reinitialized

Comment: This doesn't handle switching form subtype dynamically, and you'll nuke the previous form value when you replace the whole thing. Personally, with forms I've more often than not found that you want to be as undynamic as possible when it comes to the lifetime of the form controls; and you set/reset the form value programatically.

Comment: Changing form structure or replacing it entirely gets very problematic very soon if you, say, hook up event listeners to it; eventually you end up at a pile of spaghetti - unbind listeners, recreate form object, repopulate values, rebind lilsteners - that you wouldn't have had if you just kept using the one form object.